# Transfer Field to Array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, recordset

I am trying to transfer a field from an access table to an array.  This is the code I have and it looks correct but I am getting a Type Mismatch error:

```
Public Function GetFieldToArray() As Variant

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset: Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT 'Account ID' FROM Lookup")
    rst.MoveLast
    rst.MoveFirst
    GetFieldToArray = rst.GetRows(rst.RecordCount)

End Function
```

and here is where I am calling the function:

```
Dim pk As Variant: Set pk = GetFieldToArray()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Use `[ ]` instead of apostrophes to define object names (fields, controls, tables, queries, forms, reports) in query. Or better, don't use spaces nor punctuation/special characters nor reserved words in naming convention and `[ ]` should not be needed.

Comment: Which line exactly is it saying type mismatch? Also, I don't think you need the Set after the dim just a pk = GetFieldToArray().

Comment: @June7 that isn't the issue because it doesn't crash on the query.  I tried anyone and it did not fix it.  I know, I do not use spaces in field names.  The issue is this is imported from an excel file, which after updates are made, I export it to excel again.  So I need the spaces (in this case)

Comment: @Byrd, it crashes after I am exiting the function - therefore back where I call the function.

Comment: Your SELECT isn't technically the problem as it is valid SQL but it is not returning what you think it is (in other words if you are trying to return the values in column Account ID, this won't do it). Your SQL as written is simply going to return the string "Account ID" for as many rows as you have in table Lookup. Follow June7's advice here.  Your other problem is the "Set pk..." statement. As @Byrd notes, you don't need the "set" here as pk is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` to define object names. Apostrophes just define literal text. True, the query won't crash but also does not pull data from table. Using spaces or punctuation/special characters in naming convention or reserved words as names will require use of `[]` delimiters.

GetRows will create a 2-dimension array so must include at least two fields in query. Only first 2 will be utilized.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Account ID], [another field] FROM Lookup")
```

Don't use Set for the pk variable.

`Dim pk As Variant: pk = GetFieldToArray()`

Code using the array must reference row and column indexes but since only interested in first column, use a static input:

`Debug.Print pk(0, x)`